# Three.js GLTFLoader - как правильно клонировать объекты с анимацией?

Tags: three.js, loader, clone

Суть в том что статические объекты можно склонировать и добваить на основную сцену

```
var postMesh = gltf.scene.getObjectByName('obj');
var clone = new THREE.Mesh( postMesh.geometry, postMesh.material );
```

Но если использовать ту же функцию clone()

```
gltf.scene.clone()
```

И пробовать добавить на сцену склонированый объект - то в консоли вываливается ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at l (three.js:163)
    at l (three.js:164)
```

Вот такие дела, clone не работает должным образом, если кто-то разобрался очень прошу сообщить. Версию с гитхаба скачал месяц назад.

Comment: Скорее всего нужно использовать метод `.clone()` из [SkeletonUtils](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/utils/SkeletonUtils). `r105` И не забыть добавить сами утилиты `<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/utils/SkeletonUtils.js"></script>`

Comment: Да все верно, спасибо огромное, вчера ещё решил. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: Да не за что - сами же разобрались :)